# What happends when a recipe has more than 1 dish

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to make the structure for a recipe database.

This is what i have got so far:

[image]

I'm pretty new to databases so there might be a few misstakes.

The thing that I can't understand is: what happens when a recipe has more than 1 dish or food "accessories"? Will this database structure still work?

Like this:

[image]

Does my database structe fail or...

would be really nice if someone could explain this for me

Answer (score 1):

In our universe, recipes don't HAVE dishes; dishes HAVE recipes.  Your question is difficult to answer because I can't imagine a universe in which the same recipe produces multiple dishes.

However, a very simple structure might be:

```
Recipe (RecipeID, Name)

SauceSteps (StepID, RecipeID, StepText, Index)
DishSteps (StepID, RecipeID, StepText, Index)

DishIngredients (RecipeID, Name, Qty, Unit)
SauceIngredients (RecipeID, Name, Qty, Unit)
```

RecipeID will be a FK to the Recipe table.  With this approach, you can have many Steps or Ingredients records for each Recipe.

You could simplify this further by adding a tinyint or bool flag to decide whether each Step or Ingredient is a Sauce or Dish type.

```
Recipe (RecipeID, Name)

Steps (StepID, RecipeID, StepText, Index, Type)

Ingredients (RecipeID, Name, Qty, Unit, Type)
```